# How to create a custom route with sub-domain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I added a sub-domain to the routes in my project:

`match '/' => 'controller#action', constraints: { subdomain: /*/ }, via: [:get]`

How can I name this url format to a route path like `new_post_path`?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the subdomain as a constraint in your routes file:

```
get 'photos', to: 'photos#index', constraints: { subdomain: 'admin' }
```

You'll need to use a helper like this when creating your links:

```
photos_url(subdomain: 'admin')
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#overriding-named-route-parameters

Comment: But if I call ``redirect_to new_post_path`` or ``new_post_url`` in controller, it will go to root path instead

Comment: I've edited the answer to include a constraint when creating the link - try the new solution and let me know?